# Loading doubles that are equally spaced in memory using intel intrinsics?

Tags: c++, intrinsics

Is there an intrinsic like `_mm256_load_pd` that loads double that are equally spaced in memory?

Basically, I'm trying to load column vectors of a matrix instead of row vectors.

Comment: no, SIMD only works well on contiguous memory.  Gather loads are not very efficient, whether you use HW gathers or manual shuffles.  There is no strided load instruction.  If you're trying to write a matmul, striding down columns is not part of an efficient implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to think of intrinsics like this. The load intrinsics are for putting a chunk of data directly from one place in memory into a data type that can be loaded straight into a register. You can't do that, because the data you want to act on is not contiguous.

The easiest thing to do would just be something like:

```
__m256d data;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   data[i] = myarray[/* some index derived from i*/]
}
```

Comment: Note that indexing a `__m256d` with `[]` only works in GNU C, which defines `__m256d` in terms of GNU C native vector syntax.  MSVC defines `__m256d` differently (as a union of arrays of different types).  Anyway yes, that's one way to do a strided load, and might compile as efficiently as it's possible to do this.  But that's "not very"; much better plan your vectorization so you don't need this, e.g. at worst by transposing small chunks of the array as you need them, for cache-blocking.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I'm mostly a Linux developer so I wasn't aware of that re: the operator not being defined.As you say, it's better to avoid this completely anyway by chunking up your matrix.